# Lazyloading entities, references are loading but entity properties aren't

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I am still in the EF learning process and I am trying to get more familiar with EF lazy loading.

Please consider the following class and test:

```
[Table("Tenant")]
public class  Tenant : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public string Guid { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CaseType> CaseTypes { get; set; }

    public Tenant()
    {
        Users = new List<User>();
        CaseTypes = new List<CaseType>();
    }
}
```

And the test:

```
    [Test]
    public void TenantLazyLoading()
    {
        var tenant = _applicationContext.Tenants.Create();
        tenant.Guid = "d176dc7c-6b96-4ab6-bddf-ce5a12024c39";
        _applicationContext.Tenants.Attach(tenant);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, tenant.Users.Count); // Pass, the navigation property users was loaded (lazy)
        Assert.AreEqual("localhost", tenant.Name); // Fail, the tenant name is not loaded
    }
```

The lazy loading apparently only works on the Navigation properties, but not on the Tenant properties. I made both properties (`Users` and `Name`) virtual, but that doesn't seem to matter.

How can I `lazy load` the local properties of `Tenant`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way how it works. If you create an entity manually and `Attach` it to the context you are telling EF that you **don't want** to load the entity's scalar properties.

There is no lazy loading of scalar properties, you always must do it explicitly, either by adding...

```
_applicationContext.Entry(tenant).Reload();
```

...after `Attach` or by replacing the first three lines by:

```
var tenant = _applicationContext.Tenants
    .Find(new Guid("d176dc7c-6b96-4ab6-bddf-ce5a12024c39"));
```